# Laravel url validate without get params

Tags: php, laravel

How I can validate site link?
Example: user write url: http://example.com/get?d=323&d=323

I need get only `http://example.com/'

How I can validate?

```
$this->validate($request->all(), ['url' => 'required|url']
```

this not work. This validate url with get params..

Or how not validate this, and get in variable only `http://example.com/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use :

```
request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

to get http://example.com/

and :

```
request()->url();
```

for full path without query strings